# Parse commands for a shell like application in C

Tags: c, parsing, parameters, command

I have to create a C application that will process commands with different parameters for each command and some of them might be optional and the order might change. Similar to what getopt does but not from command line. Also getopt needs '-' to recognize the options and I dont need to type in '-'. I has to be a shell like application. I could have a command like "set" and different parameters like "voltage" , "frequency" or "duty"and their respective values. For example:

```
set voltage 10 frequency 1500
set frequency 500
set voltage 4 duty 20
```

Do I have to implement all the logic or is there a variation of getopts that could do all this for me?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad to be on-topic here, I think. But my suggestion would be to look into tools like lex + yacc. [Try starting here, for example.](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/tutorials/au-lexyacc/)

Comment: Read a line from the console, then `split` that line and process the results.

Comment: If your 
target is posix-like, it's possible that [wordexp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html#) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Or maybe not :-) Read the docs carefully. Here's the Gnu docs (with code sample): https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Calling-Wordexp.html

Comment: If you wanted to parse a variation like `set voltage=10,frequency=1500` where you have `key=value` pairs separated by commas, you could use POSIX [`getsubopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsubopt.html) to process the string after the keyword `set`.  Otherwise, you can write some ad hoc functionality to handle it, or you can use Lex+Yacc (or, these days, Flex+Bison) or a similar tool to do the job.  Actually, Lex or Flex alone is probably sufficient.  Presumably there is some other command than just `set` that must be recognized and acted upon.